# CFG OPLIST Confusion

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

I am trying to derive a grammar for this expression:

> An operands list is a comma-separated list of zero or more terms bracketed with parentheses.

It should be like `OPList = ...`

Could someone help me out? The English on this has got me a little lost

Answer (score 1):

OK, lets look at the English. Comma-separated terms is easy:

```
term, term, term, ...
```

Zero or more is easy, as that says the whole list can be empty. Bracketed with parenthesis is ambiguous. It could mean the whole list can be in brackets like this:

```
(term, term, term)
```

Or, it could mean that each term is in brackets, like this:

```
(term), (term), (term)
```

The use of the **with** would usually imply the latter style.

This gives us a CFG of:

```
OPList : element | List "," element |
List : element "," List | element
element : "(" term ")"
```

Comment: Although I've answered the question, it might be better suited to [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)